# Two Sided Pagination in Symfony Bottom and Top

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working in Symfony, just startup with it and learning it.

I am using sonataadmin to create admin module, and the requirement is like have to put pagination bottom and top.

It is working fine in the bottom side. I need same on the top side.

I override listing template and i know this is the block of pagination :

```
{% block pager_links %}
{% if admin.datagrid.pager.haveToPaginate() %}
{% include admin.getTemplate('pager_links') %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am putting this same block on the upper side of the twig template.

> Erorr : The block 'pager_links' has already been defined

Can anyone please help me in that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `{% block pager_links %}`a block from sonata or one you have created ?

Comment: It is default block of sonata. So it is creating pagination at bottom perfectly but page is not allow me to put same block in the same file, i need both side pagination.

Comment: can't you put `{% if admin.datagrid.pager.haveToPaginate() %}
{% include admin.getTemplate('pager_links') %}
{% endif %}`in another block ?

Comment: It's Working Thanks .